# How to get the student id where student got grade A but not C

Tags: sql

table
.......

```
student_id   Grade
1              A
1              B
1              D
2              B
2              C
2              A
```

Desired Output
.............

```
student_id
1
```

i have tried 
............

```
select student_id from student where grade='A' and not grade='c';
```

but i am getting wrong output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select by grades of `A`, left join to grades again by `student_id` and grade `C`, and exclude matches.

```
select distinct
 a.student_id
from grades as a
  left join grades as c
  on c.student_id = a.student_id
  and c.Grade = 'C'
where a.Grade = 'A'
and c.student_id is null -- exclude students with C's
```

Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a2dab/2).

Answer (score 2):

One simple method is aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select student_id
from student
group by student_id
having sum(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when grade = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```